# Avoid replacing/mixing user contexts in apollo-server datasources during the execution of asynchronous code

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

This question might be somewhat stupid but I like to make sure to not mess this up:

> If you use this.context in your datasource, it's critical to create 
>   a new instance in the dataSources function and to not share a single
>   instance.  Otherwise, initialize may be called during the execution of
>   asynchronous code  for a specific user, and replace the this.context
>   by the context of another user.

[Source](https://www.w3resource.com/apollo-graphql/connect-a-database.php)

**Question:** Is the following appropriate to avoid mixing/replacing user context during execution of async code?

**main.js**

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => {
    return {
      foo: new FooAPI() <- is this considered 'create a new instance in the dataSources function'?
    }
  },
  context: (event) => {
    return {
      use_id: event.user_id <- (provided by auth middleware)
    }
  }
})
```

**MyCustomDatasource.js**

```
class MyCustomDatasource extends DataSource {
  constructor ({ type, tableName, region, apiVersion }) {
    super()
    // db specific stuff
  }

  initialize (config) {
    this.context = config.context <- save due to 'new instance in the dataSources function'?
    this.cache = config.cache

    .
    .
    .
  }
```

**FooAPI.js**

```
class FooAPI extends MyCustomDatasource {
  constructor () {
    super({
      // foo db params
    })
  }

  // Query   
  async allByUser () {
    return await super.query({
      KCE: `
        #user_id = :user_id 
        AND begins_with(#id, :id)
      `,
      EAN: {
        '#user_id': 'user_id',
        '#id': 'id'
      },
      EAV: {
        ':user_id': this.context.user_id, <- save due to 'new instance in the dataSources function'?
        ':id': 'foo'
      },
      Limit: 10
    })
  }
```

**foo resolver**

```
{

  Query: {   
    foos (parent, args, context, info) {
      const { foo } = context.dataSources

      return foo.allByUser()
    }
  },
```